# clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE returned value meaning

Tags: opencl

I think the clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo's return value's meaning with CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE type is the maximum workitems in one workgroup; which equals dim[0] * dim[1] * ... * dim[dims-1]; is this understanding correct? For example, if the return value is 256, then I cannot set local work group size with (16,16,2), which 16 * 16 * 2 = 512 which is bigger than 256.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct. The *local_work_size* argument to  [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html):

> Points to an array of work_dim unsigned values that describe the number of work-items that make up a work-group (also referred to as the **size of the work-group**) that will execute the kernel specified by kernel. **The total number of work-items in a work-group is computed as
>
>   local_work_size[0] *... * local_work_size[work_dim - 1]**.

[clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html) with argument CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:

> This provides a mechanism for the application to query the **maximum work-group size** that can be used to execute a kernel on a specific device given by device.

You may also want to make sure the local size in each dimension is no greater than CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES ([clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)). There is no similar parameter in clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo, so there appears to be no kernel-specific limit to each dimension.